# Why can't I airdrop my notes from my mac to my iDevice?

Tags: macos, notes.app, airdrop

In **Notes** app I have some notes stored: **On My Mac**

my share menu though only gives me the following choices:

[image: share menu]

when I click **More...**

[image: more menu]

AirDrop is selected and at the top!

Mail and Messages shows up, but no AirDrop.

How can I AirDrop my Notes from mac to iDevice?

---

edit: already fixed in macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot share notes via Airdrop from a Mac.

I have checked four Macs (all running either El Capitan or Sierra) and in each case I find the exact same situation as you. More specifically, trying to share a note does **not** give me the option of using Airdrop **and** if I click on the *More...* option I also see AirDrop listed with a ticked checkmark (greyed out just like in your screenshot).

This is not something I had noticed previously as I haven't tried to share a Note from any of my Macs.

Now, I also checked whether this is a known issue and found [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6775592?) on Apple's website. Although it was started in January 2015, you'll see that the most recent post was (at the time of writing this) just over a week ago.

I'm not entirely sure why sharing notes via AirDrop from a Mac isn't an option (although the fact that notes are all stored *within* the Notes app and can be synced via iCloud may be part of the reason).

I suggest you send [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

If you do need a way to share your notes via Airdrop, then there's a few workarounds online (including within the above-mentioned discussion). The one I like most is to do as follows:

1. Within the Notes app, open the note you want to share
2. Go to File > Export as PDF...
3. Click Save
4. Within Finder, navigate to the exported PDF
5. Right-click on the file
6. Select Share > AirDrop

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because Notes are now synced across all devices with the same Apple ID?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. Regardless, it's not consistent behaviour and is actually bad UX design. After all, if we can share a note to _other_ users via Messages, etc, then why not via AirDrop? Just seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

In the notes app on your MacBook go to File > Share > Airdrop

I had the same issue as you, but found this way is simpler than the previous answer.

Comment: I thin k this was more of a Sierra problem, already fixed in High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when changing macbook. I used the following workaround which uses iCloud only very briefly:

- on the source Mac open iCloud preferences
- enable iCloud for Notes on the "source Mac"
- drag and drop all your notes from "On My Mac" to "iCloud"
- enable iCloud for Notes on the "target Mac"
- all your notes should appear on the target Mac in category iCloud
- open Notes preferences, and select "Enable the On My Mac account"
- drag all notes from the "iCloud" to "On My Mac"
- go back to iCloud preferences and disable iCloud for Notes on both Macs

Max